# Integral Ornstein Uhlenbeck

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been reading about the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process related to Langevin dynamics and am a bit confused as to how the following is completed. So when solving the Ornstein Uhlenbeck SDE $$\dot{x}\gamma x(t)=A(t) $$ where A is noise, we get an equation for a variable like, $$x(t)=x(0)e^{-\gamma(t)}+\int^{t}_{0}e^{\gamma(t'-t)}A(t')dt' $$ Next the book says take the correlation function of $x(t_{1})$ and $x(t_{2})$ firstly I am unsure now as to why the following is the case and I think it is essential because I know that Ito's issosymetry can be used when there is an expectation value and I no that this is related to the correlation, so the correlation function is therefore, $$<x(t_{1}),x(t_{2})>=x(0)^{2}e^{-2\gamma t}+ e^{-2\gamma t}\int^{t}_{0}\int^{t}_{0}e^{\gamma(t_{1}+t_{2})}\delta(t_{1}-t_{2}) dt'_{1}dt'_{2} $$ Now I know that Ito issosymetry can be used to deal with this integral but I no that there needs to be an expectation value so basically I think I am confused as to how to take a correlation function of two variables and then how to get an expectation value as a result, I know how to solve the problem using Ito's isosymetry just not how the expectation value arrises after taking the correlation function.

I can't add comments so i have to keep re-editing.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *Ornstein--Uhlenbeck*?

Comment: Neither (stochastic-calculus) nor OU here.

Comment: OP: Since you just added back "Ornstein-Uhlenbeck" in the title after I suppressed it (with comment), could you explain how it is relevant? Note that the words do not even appear in the question. With this logic, the title of every question involving min(s,t) should contain the words "Brownian motion"...

Comment: @Did OU process = Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process...? So, as far as I can see, the words (or at least, the abbreviation) appear in the question.

Comment: @saz It has been [edited](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/575802/revisions). Drastically.